# Grammar Error (Articles)

Tags: grammar, articles

I need to know why 'a' is omitted before headache in the below sentence.

> Although he has undergone a very costly treatment, he has not been cured of *a* headache.

Correct - cured of headache.

Comment: Buy we say. I have a headache. I'm right?

Comment: I was cured of a headache last month, but I have not been cured of my headache this time. Last month is not specified, this time is.

Comment: Actually, here, *headache* is uncountable: it's used as the name of a condition, in the same way as the word *epilepsy* might occur in that position.

Comment: He wants to be cured of a tendency to headache, not just a particular episode of it.

Comment: Who says it should be omitted?

Comment: "cured of headache" sounds wrong to me. "cured of headaches" suggests a permanent cure. "cured of *the* headache" would be specific to the headache that the treatment was targeted at.

Comment: *I need to know why 'a' is omitted before headache in the below sentence.* We need to know the context in which this was said, and the source. As it stands, with and without the "a", it is not idiomatic.

Comment: The sentence is a exercise question in the articles section of the book which I'm studying.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a dictionary mentioning it but there is little doubt that "headache" is both countable and uncountable, which explains the use with no article in a non-plural context.

([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/headache)) (not mentioned)  You will find one instance of uncountable use.

([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/headache?q=headache)) (not mentioned, which according to  this dictionary is an indication that the word is only countable; it could be an omission.)